# ngChange for multiple ngModels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to call a function if one of multiple `ngModel` values change, without adding a `$scope.$watch`?

Change this:

```
<div>
    <input ng-model="value1" ng-change="update()">
    <input ng-model="value2" ng-change="update()">
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div ng-changes="update()">
    <input ng-model="value1" >
    <input ng-model="value2">
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you asked the question just so you can answer yourself after 30 seconds?

Comment: @yarons I found a solution while writing the question. Why not share it?

Comment: That's an interesting issue. If you already know the answer, is there a point in asking the question? I should ask that on Meta I guess...

Comment: why not [`$watchCollection`](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2901-using-scope-watchcollection-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm)?

Comment: @PankajParkar Why `ngChange` if you could `$watch`? Because it's not the same.

Comment: @hansmaad Its just an alternative way which I thought.. I know they are different. but it would work as same as `ngChange`, once you register `wathcer` after values are populated.

Comment: @hansmaad, I stand corrected. Apparently it's an acceptable and even [encouraged practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the simple implementation of `ngChange`, you can traverse the child tree, collect all `ngModelControllers` and register the callback in `$viewChangeListeners`.

```
function ngChanges() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(element[0].querySelectorAll("*"), function(e) {
            var ngModel = angular.element(e).controller('ngModel');
            if (ngModel) {                
              ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
                scope.$eval(attr.onChanges);
              })
            }
      })
    }
  }
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71063jq6/3/)

Comment: Could be be better will `[ng-model]` selector.